# Why doesn't the link to the image part work on the Github blog?

Tags: html, github, blogs

When I check it with visual studio code live server, it works fine, but when I apply it to my blog, only the images are displayed and the link function disappears.

At first, I thought the issue was due to the script I added to make it work on responsive web, but even after removing the script, the partial image link still doesn't work.

There is absolutely no problem with the link, I have checked it many times, and I checked it again before writing the post

```
<img src="../images/map.png" usemap="#image-map">

<map name="image-map">
    <area target="_blank" alt="img" title="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/" coords="4734,3163,6576,3722" shape="rect">
</map>
```

**Previous code**

(https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-rwdImageMaps/1.6/jquery.rwdImageMaps.min.js"></script>
  <style>  
    img {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <
  <img src="../images/2023-01-29-0001/map.png" usemap="#instaMap" width="500" height="500">
  <map name="instaMap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="4673,5113,5337,5737" href="https://www.instagram.com/">
    
  </map>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```